# Create/Update google drive permission in Go/ [Created spreadsheet using api but have no access to it]

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, file-permissions

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet using google drive api with the following code, but I have no access to it.

[**update**: the file doesn't seem to be in the drive I specified here, anyone know why is that happening?]

[**update**: added parents in the field, but have 404 error, says file not found, thanks in advance if anyone knows the reason.]

```
func (dr *driveService) CreateFile(driveId string, fileName string, parents []string) (*drive.File, error) {
    file := &drive.File{
        DriveId:  driveId,
        Name:     fileName,
        MimeType: mimeTypeSpreadsheet,
        Parents:  parents,
        
    }
    file, err := dr.googleDriveService.Files.Create(file).Do()
    return file, err
}
```

So i tried to create/update the permissions using this code, but this error occurs `Error 403: The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable., fieldNotWritable`

```
func (dr *driveService) CreatePermission(fileId string, permissionType string, permissionRole string) error {
    permissionToBeCreated := &drive.Permission{
        Type: permissionType,
        Role: permissionRole,
    }
    filePermission, err := dr.googleDriveService.Permissions.Create(fileId, permissionToBeCreated).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("An error occurred creating permission for file: %v\n", err)
        return err
    }

    _, err = dr.googleDriveService.Permissions.Update(fileId, filePermission.Id,filePermission).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("An error occurred: %v\n", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

So tried to remove the `update` part in the second function, but there's `nil` for the permissions of the file.

So, does someone have any idea how to fix this? or in general how can I create a spreadsheet that everyone has the link can access it?

Thanks!

Comment: `[update: the file doesn't seem to be in the drive I specified here, anyone know why is that happening?]` How do you know that? Did you check it on the UI? Or did you try to access it via API? If it's the latter, can you show the corresponding code?

Comment: @Iamblichus No, I simply checked the drive folder and didn't it the file anywhere. Also, I tried to list the files within the drive by the code below. While debugging, I can fine the file, but there is `nil` in the field for drive id for that file i created.

Comment: ```func (s *sheetCreator) getExistingSpreadsheet(list *drive.FileList, spreadsheetName string) (bool, string) {
 for _, file := range list.Files {
  name := file.Name
  if name == spreadsheetName {
   fmt.Print(file.DriveId)
   //s.driveService.Delete(file.Id)
   return true, file.Id
  }
 }
 return false, ""
}```

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you create a spreadsheet in a certain shared drive, and when you visit the shared drive using an account that has access to it, you cannot find the spreadsheet? I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Is the `parent` you specify located in the specified `drive`? Are you sure you are checking that parent?

Comment: yes the parent was correct, thanks and i found the mistake was ```file, err := dr.googleDriveService.Files.Create(file).Do()``` here, should have `supportAllDrives` set as `true`. Otherwise it won't work. Thank you tho!

Comment: That's interesting, since `supportsAllDrives` is supposed to be deprecated since June 2020. What version of the library are you using?

Comment: im using v3 google drive api, if that's what you mean? In my version the `supportsTeamDrive` is deprecated but not `supportAllDrives`.

Comment: It's supposed to be deprecated, but the docs are not showing that anymore, at least for now. I could find a reference to it in the Python library though: `supportsAllDrives: boolean, Deprecated - Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives. This parameter will only be effective until June 1, 2020. Afterwards all applications are assumed to support shared drives.` (I created a file in a shared drive using this library, no `supportsAllDrives` set). https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html

Comment: I meant the go library you're using, not the version of the API.

Comment: In any case, are you sure this was not working and it started working after you added `supportsAllDrives`? If that's the case, could you post an answer with this?

Comment: yeah, I'll post an answer! Btw, do you know why when I use the sheet-api delete a sheet within the spreadsheet (that sheet can be seen deleted on the UI), but it still exist in the spreadsheet  `sheet` field?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by setting `supportAllDrives` as true while creating the file.
However this should already be deprecated but not on mine version.

**Edit**:

Looks like `supportsAllDrives` is not being deprecated anymore, at least for now. The deprecation note cannot be found anymore on the official docs, so it seems this is still supported.

Also, looking at [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api), it looks like changes to shared drives have been postponed:

> **Editor's note**: Due to current events the Google team has made the decision to avoid causing additional disruption during this uncertain time. As a result, we're postponing the proposed changes regarding the opt-in mechanism for shared drives indefinitely. Shared drives and files within a shared drive will only be returned when requests set the relevant opt-in parameters.

Comment: Hi, thank you for providing an answer. Please note that the deprecation note cannot be found anymore on the official docs so, at least officially, this is still supported.

Comment: Looking at [this article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api), it looks like changes to shared drives have been postponed: `Editor's note: Due to current events the Google team has made the decision to avoid causing additional disruption during this uncertain time. As a result, we're postponing the proposed changes regarding the opt-in mechanism for shared drives indefinitely. Shared drives and files within a shared drive will only be returned when requests set the relevant opt-in parameters.`